# how to call mysql procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

i created a procedure in mysql

```
  DELIMITER // 
   create procedure insert_trans_id (IN $Project_Code varchar(100),IN $user_name 
   varchar(100),IN $item_name varchar(100),IN $Unit_Name 
   varchar(100),IN $item_size1 varchar(50),IN $item_qty1 int,IN $l_name varchar(100)
   )
   begin
  //variable declare here
   declare $p_id int;
   declare $user_id int;
   declare $i_id int;
   declare $unit_id int;
   declare $item_size varchar(50);       
   declare $item_qty int;
   declare $loc_id int;
   //setting variables
   set @item_size = ($item_size1);
   set @item_qty  = ($item_qty1);
   set @p_id      = (SELECT `id` FROM `project_master` WHERE `Project_Code` `enter code here`= $Project_Code) ;
   set @user_id   = ( SELECT  `u_id` FROM `user` WHERE `user_name` = $user_name);
   set @i_id      =(SELECT `id` FROM `item_master` WHERE `item_name` = $item_name);
   set @unit_id   = (SELECT `id` FROM `unit_mstr` WHERE `Unit_Name` = $Unit_Name);
   set @loc_id    = (SELECT `id` FROM `location_mstr` WHERE `l_name` = $l_name);
   PREPARE STMT FROM 
 // insert statement 
"INSERT INTO `project_transaction_header`(`project_id`, `u_id`, `item_Id`,`unit_id`,`Size`, `Qty`, `location_id`, `Created_On`, `Created_By`,`Modified_on`, `Modified_By`)VALUES(p_id,user_id,i_id,$unit_id,item_size,item_qty,loc_id,'system',now(),'system',now() )";

EXECUTE STMT USING @p_id,@user_id,@i_id,@$unit_id,@item_size,@item_qty,@loc_id;
END
```

its working fine in mysql phpmyadmin but i don,t now how to call same procedure in php 
help me if possible example needed

Comment: You need to format this question better. Its impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can call to a procedure using `call insert_trans_id(parameter1,parameter2)`

You can read in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)

To fetch the result of an sp read the example #3 in the link above

Comment: i am already try to call procedure like this but nothing happen.  session_start();
  include('config.inc');
  $rs = mysql_query($connect, 'CALL insert_trans_id('$Project_Code','$user_name','$item_name','$Unit_Name','$item_size','$item_qty','$lname)' );

Comment: when i call like this blank page comes and nothing happen :(

Comment: how are you fetching the result...in the link i posted has the step to get the result of stored procedure..read the example #3

Comment: when i tried to call like if (!$mysqli->multi_query("CALL insert_trans_id($Project_Code ,$user_name,$item_name,$Unit_Name,$item_size,$item_qty,$lname)")) {
    echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
 this whole code (procdure) comes in the frontend :( and nothing.i just want to insert value in the table by help of this procedure. when values inserted successfully i want to come back in the same page.i am new in php